# Как изменить заголовок страницы в reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Всем привет использую react-router 
У меня есть файл Appbar.jsx в котором написан title

```
      <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
          Title
      </Typography>
```

есть файл в котором прописан роутинг

```
 <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
<Route path="/events" component={Events}/>
```

Когда я перехожу по роутингу все работает хорошо, но мне надо поменять заголовок title если я в файл обавляю

```
<Route exact path='/' component={titleHome}/>
```

То он не работает... точнее работает если нажать F5 но так работать не должно.... `<Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>` отрабатывает без перезагрузки страницы как это и должно быть, подскажите как сделать так что бы при разном роутинге в другом файле менялись заголовки?

Comment: используейте withRouter
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: не сочтите за наглость, но можно пример? - я с ReactJS совсем недавно только начал работать

Comment: так я ссылку скинул там несколько примеров даже... оборачиваете ваш компонент withRouter(<Component />) и при смене роута у вас будут менятся props в Component